# PHP HTML DOMDocument getElementById problems

Tags: php, html, parsing

A little new to PHP parsing here, but I can't seem to get PHP's DOMDocument to return what is clearly an identifiable node.  The HTML loaded will come from the 'net so can't necessarily guarantee XML compliance, but I try the following:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$html = '<html><body>Hello <b id="bid">World</b>.</body></html>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;

/*** load the html into the object ***/
$dom->loadHTML($html);
var_dump($dom);    
    
$belement = $dom->getElementById("bid");
var_dump($belement);

?>
```

Though I receive no error, I only receive the following as output:

```
object(DOMDocument)#1 (0) {
}
NULL
```

Should I not be able to look up the `<b>` tag as it does indeed have an id?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The Manual](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-domdocument-getelementbyid.php) explains why:

> For this function to work, you will need either to set some ID attributes with DOMElement->setIdAttribute() or a DTD which defines an attribute to be of type ID. In the later case, you will need to validate your document with DOMDocument->validate() or DOMDocument->validateOnParse before using this function.

By all means, go for valid HTML & provide a DTD.

Quick fixes:

1. Call `$dom->validate();` and put up with the errors (or fix them), afterwards you can use `$dom->getElementById()`, regardless of the errors for some reason.
2. Use XPath if you don't feel like validing: `$x = new DOMXPath($dom); $el = $x->query("//*[@id='bid']")->item(0);`
3. Come to think of it: if you just set `validateOnParse` to true **before** loading the HTML, if would also work ;P

.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html ='<html>
<body>Hello <b id="bid">World</b>.</body>
</html>';
$dom->validateOnParse = true; //<!-- this first
$dom->loadHTML($html);        //'cause 'load' == 'parse

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$belement = $dom->getElementById("bid");
echo $belement->nodeValue;
```

Outputs 'World' here.

Comment: I do have validateOnParse.  setIdAttribute only would apply to set and then subsequent retrieve?  Again though, the HTML will be web-provided so I'm at their mercy, but just trying an example.  HTML5 doesn't even have a DTD, yes?

Comment: "setIdAttribute only would apply to set and then subsequent retrieve?" -> Yes. HTML5 is not finished yet so it should not have a DTD yet.

Comment: DTD would be `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, but just calling `$dom->validate()` would also work. Put up with the errors or try to generate valid HTML (the latter is more difficult than it seems... :) )

Comment: @Xepoch I've never managed to get `getElementById` working when using `DOM` with HTML. But you can substitute `getElementById` with an XPath like `//p[@id="foo"]`

Comment: @Wrikken doesnt work for me. I'm getting *Trying to get property of non-object* on the `echo` call with PHP 5.3.2 on Vista and libxml 20703

Comment: Hmm, here it does work, PHP 5.3.2, libxml 2.7.6 (I assume for Windows, 20703 would be 2.7.3), you could try ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/libxml2-2.7.6.win32.zip . Calling `validate()` manually later on also no results?

Comment: ... and if that doesn't work, have you tried using the example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/domimplementation.createdocument.php ?

Comment: @Wrikken Doing `validate()` only gets me a couple of errors about the `html40/loose.dtd` and the same error as before. Using the explicit DTD declaration doesnt help either. Ive tried on an XP machine with 5.3.0 and libxml 20626 and nothing as well. I guess this is either a Windows thing or a libxml thing. I'll try to update it. Upvoted nonetheless though.

Comment: @Gordon: OK, duly noted that this isn't cross-os/version behavior. Thankfully if works on my servers :) The XPath stays a failsafe fallback afaik.

Comment: @Wrikken after upgrading PHP to 5.3.3 which comes bundled with libxml 2.7.7, getElementById is working.

Comment: OK, good news, nice to know live just got that little bit easier :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should check if `$dom->loadHTML($html);` returns true (success) and I would try

```
 var_dump($belement->nodeValue);
```

for output to get a clue what might be wrong.

**EDIT:**
http://www.php-editors.com/php_manual/function.domdocument-get-element-by-id.html - it seems that DOMDocument uses XPath internally.

**Example:**

```
$xpath = xpath_new_context($dom);
var_dump(xpath_eval_expression($xpath, "//*[@ID = 'YOURIDGOESHERE']"));
```

Comment: Original post modified to reflect these outputs.  Thanks,