# Remove paragraph by id with PHP DOM

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to find paragraphs with the id "test" and remove them from a html string, I've tried using php DOMDocument but the html I'm searching is badly formed and I get errors

```
$caption = "blah blah<p id ='test'>Test message</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile($caption);
$xmessage = $doc->getElementById('test');
```

returns

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : br i

Is there a way to suppress the warnings?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following code to remove a para with `id='test'`:

```
$caption = "blah blah<p id='test'>Test message</p><p id='foo'>Foo Bar</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($caption);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nlist = $xpath->query("//p[@id='test']");
$node = $nlist->item(0);
echo "Para: [" . $node->nodeValue . "]\n";
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
echo "Remaining: [" . $doc->saveHTML() . "]\n";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Para: [Test message]
Remaining: [<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<p>blah blah</p>
<p id="foo">Foo Bar</p>
</body></html>
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`loadHTMLFile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) use [`loadHTML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

The latter expects HTML string, which is what you are providing. Doing so should correct the warning.

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementById`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) requires the HTML to be [validated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php) before it'll work.  See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3392081) for more info.

```
$caption = "blah blah<p id ='test'>Test message</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->validateOnParse = true;  // validate HTML
$doc->loadHTML($caption);  // This loads an HTML string
$xmessage = $doc->getElementById('test');
```

(NOTE: You need to use [`loadHTML`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php), not [`loadHTMLFile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)).

This still may not work, as the HTML may not be valid.

If this doesn't work, I suggest using [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

```
$caption = "blah blah<p id ='test'>Test message</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile($caption);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xmessage = $xpath->query("//p[@id='test']")->item(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

There's more than one paragraph with the same ID? Surely not...

It's generally bad practice (as the warnings are there for a reason), but you can suppress warnings using @, although i'm not 100% certain it works on function calls from a class like this, let me know if it does!

```
$caption = "blah blah<p id ='test'>Test message</p>";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($caption);
$xmessage = @$doc->getElementById('test');
```

Comment: Using the `@` works fine here, but the problem was that he was using the wrong method.  `loadHTMLFile` expects a file name, he wanted `loadHTML` which takes a string of HTML.

Comment: Thanks but get "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in"