# Is it possible to achieve same using getElementById

Tags: php, dom

With the code below I can get elements of an html table using DOM's getElementsByTagName and it works.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile("any.html");

## get table by tagName

$tables= $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$table = $tables->item(0);

foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as  $key =>$tr){
     $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

but  I  want to get table by getElementById.  Is it possible by using table's id?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetElementById Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391942/php-html-domdocument-getelementbyid-problems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need to do this first:

```
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
```

then

```
$tableId = 'someId';
$table = $dom->getElementById($tableId);

foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as  $key =>$tr){
     $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I get the error "Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object"

Comment: @mustafa - does the table exist for with id?

Comment: Yes there is a html table with id 'tableid'.

Comment: @mustafa and did you change 'someId' in the above code with 'tableid' before you tried the code?

Comment: @Gordon : yes, here is the line: $table= $dom->getElementById('tableid');