# How to use getElementById

Tags: php, dom

I want to get  the values inside tds. I can do it by getElementsByTagName but I could not manage it by using getElementById.

The HTML might look like this:

```
<table id="myid">
<tr>
<td>value1</td>
<td>value2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>value1</td>
<td>value2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The php used to access the values is:

```
<?PHP
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLfile('http://remoteDomain/thispage.html');
$table=$dom->getElementById('myid');

    foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') as  $key =>$tr){
       $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

I got the error:
**Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in ...**

**EDIT2**

Php info:

DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.7.3

Operating system: Windows

Comment: you forgot to `echo` the nodeValue

Comment: In case you get "Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() blah" make sure to have a recent version of libxml. You can either install those manually or by upgrading PHP to a more recent version.

Comment: exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605362/is-it-possible-to-achieve-same-using-getelementbyid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use in foreach getElementById, and your code is working.

As it could be seen there is difference in the name `getElement[S]ByTagName` and `getElementById`, with purpose.

The definition of **id** is so to say to be unique identifier of element in a page, so only one **id** (unique) value is assumed to persist on single page and this value cannot be assigned to another element id. If you have more than one element with the same id value, it is wrong (since HTML 4 or XHTML 1.0, I think).

The way you use, looks valid.

**EDIT**

In this case you may have an anwser here: [Same problem already solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391942/php-html-domdocument-getelementbyid-problems)

Comment: @mustafa "my code is not working" is not helpful. Not at all. Explain your problems if you want help.

Comment: @mustafa, your problem has been met before here in Stack Overflow, see my edited answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `getElementById` needs a DOCTYPE. If you add

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

at the beginning of the file, it should work (you should also add html and body tags).

**Edit:** Also you need to put `$dom->validateOnParse = true;` before you load the HTML file.

This is apparently a "feature" of the `DomDocument` class, see http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php (comments)

Comment: `loadHTMLFile` will add any missing HTML skeleton and treat the HTML as HTML 4 Transitional.

Comment: validateOnParse will most of the time not help. Upgrading PHP or rather libxml will.

Comment: That's what the PHP doc says though. I tried it with `validateOnParse` turned off and it didn't work then (PHP 5.3.6; Ubuntu).

Comment: see http://codepad.viper-7.com/V9BFhj. no validateOnParse but recent libxml. then compare with http://codepad.org/s3r6mggB

Comment: Yea it's not that I don't belive you, I just wanted to point out that it worked for me :)

Comment: If I have created my document by starting with a `new DOMDocument()` and composing it from there, how do I add the DOCTYPE tag?

Answer (score 1):

you need quotes on your id attribute

```
<table id="myid">
```

Comment: The original table has quotes around id

Comment: Uh well your question didn't show that until you changed it - but thanks for the downvote - last time I answer one of your questions.

Comment: he doesnt need quotes around the id attribute as long as he loads the html with loadHTML or loadHTMLFile. libxml will use the html parser module then and autocorrect that. the answer is just wrong.

Comment: He stated that the HTML which was outputted was id=myid - that's not valid HTML and the ID attribute would be unusable.

Comment: it would be invalid but not unusable. libxml's html parser can handle invalid html and will autocorrect it. see http://codepad.viper-7.com/V9BFhj. The issue here is the outdated libxml version. Adding quotes around the id will do nothing there. See http://codepad.org/7cIFjwrw

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` as the name suggests, will only work if the element you're targeting actually has an `id`.

Comment: Yes there is an id for that table

Comment: Your `<td>` tags will need an `id` attribute you want to target them directly with `getElementById`. Are you trying to target the `table` or the `td`??